# How to enable Extjs filters on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I want to filter my grid with different buttons that active certain filters. However they do not work on page load. Only when you select/deselect a filter option and then click the button, does the filter actually kick in.

When the page first loads and you click a button, you get the following error:

```
TypeError: filter is undefined
```

How do I enable these filter settings when the page first loads?

To recreate the error. Load the fiddle and try clicking the buttons and notice they don't work. Then activate one of the filters and try again. The buttons will work after a filter is activated.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v)

**Buttons**

```
 var openButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Open Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Open/Current');
            }
        });
        var holdButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'On Hold Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Hold');
            }
        });
        var closedButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Closed Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Archived/Closed');
            }
        });
```

**Columns**

```
columns: [{
        text: 'Title',
        width: 260,
        dataIndex: 'Title',
        filterable: true,
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
                // specify disabled to disable the filter menu
                //, disabled: true
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Description',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'Description',
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
                // specify disabled to disable the filter menu
                //, disabled: true
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Modified',
        width: 90,
        dataIndex: 'Modified',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        filter: true
    }, {
        text: 'Status',
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'TopicStateValue',
        filter: {
            active: true,
            type: 'list',
            value: 'Open/Current',
            options: ['Open/Current', 'Archived/Closed', 'Hold']
        }
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the filter exists before pass value to it, if not, add it like this:

```
 var openButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Open Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
                if (!filter) {
                    filter = grid[uniqueId].filters
                            .addFilter({
                                type : 'string',
                                dataIndex : 'TopicStateValue'
                            });
                }
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Open/Current');
            }
        });
        var holdButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'On Hold Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
                if (!filter) {
                    filter = grid[uniqueId].filters
                            .addFilter({
                                type : 'string',
                                dataIndex : 'TopicStateValue'
                            });
                }
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Hold');
            }
        });
        var closedButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Closed Topics',
            handler: function () {
                var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
                if (!filter) {
                    filter = grid[uniqueId].filters
                            .addFilter({
                                type : 'string',
                                dataIndex : 'TopicStateValue'
                            });
                }
                filter.setActive(true);
                filter.setValue('Archived/Closed');
            }
        });
```

Comment: @PT_C checking and adding filters every time you use it doesn't seems right, **please try my solution below**. It could save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the filters manually before you use them.

Please add the below code to your grid panel.

```
listeners: {
            beforeRender:function() {
                this.filters.createFilters();
            }
        },
```

I tried that on your fiddle and it works.